# Android Calendar get year

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to display in the `DatePickerDialog` the next year, but I get 1900. What is the problem with this code?

```
.get(Calendar.YEAR + 1),
```

Comment: You have to use `get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1` your actual solution is broken.`get()` method takes one argument that determines which field from Calendar should be returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1,
```

Comment: and if I wanted to get the default date in my TextView?
nza.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.  I don't understand your follow on question.  Please elaborate.

Comment: how to set next year in my textview??
      .setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));

Comment: Are you asking me if that code is correct?  Did you try it?  You will likely need to format that to a string using a Date Formatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a datepicker with only year (Year Calendar) , then please refer [YearPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53300524/7200297)
 for more information. its an customized yearPicker

[image]