# date picker show only year to select in android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

i just want to create date picker dialog in which it's show only years option to choose .

Only year option is visible and user pick any year from dialog box .

Comment: Show your code, and what you did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display year only in date picker in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793811/how-to-display-year-only-in-date-picker-in-android)

Comment: Check this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: @aniruddha simple date picker is created , but i have to show only year option to pick in android ICS .

Comment: This link may help anyone who has the same issue: http://www.geekcodehub.com/2018/05/23/custom-year-picker-in-android/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

for this, try number picker instead of datepicker, see below links:

[link1](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6418-android-adventures-pickers.html?start=2)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805040/how-to-create-a-number-picker-dialog)