# how could I get only year list dialog

Tags: java, android, date

I want create a list picker that shows only year.

But I want that current year will increase automatically in next year.

I tried do this with DatePicker but it doesn't show only year picker.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use java.time

Use the java.time classes, the modern replacement for the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Determining the year means determining the date. Determining the date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

If not specified, your JVM’s current default time zone is applied. That default varies, even *during* runtime. So better to always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

As you want only the year, this time zone issues obviously applies only around the end/beginning of the year. But you might as well program it to generically work all 365 or 366 days of the year.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Lastly interrogate for the year.

```
int year = ld.getYear();
```

Calculate next year and last year.

```
int nextYear = ( year + 1 );
int lastYear = ( year - 1 );
```

Now use those values to display a number picker.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Comment: Thanks @Basil for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible using the default TimePicker. You could, however, implement MH.'s "hacky" [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793811/how-to-display-year-only-in-date-picker-in-android).

Alternatively, you could simply use a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and make it list the years you would like to have available.