# How to show only year in spinner

Tags: android, datepicker

Creating app in which i want to show only year in spinner.I am using DatepickerDialog which is showing date,month and year but i want to show only year.

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {

                datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
                // datePicker.getYear();
                // year = selectedYear;
                tvYearSelection.setText(new StringBuilder().append(datePicker.getYear()));
            }
        }, year, 0, 0);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: try to use NumberPicker with custom adapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display year only in date picker in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793811/how-to-display-year-only-in-date-picker-in-android)

Comment: That is not working..

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private void createDialogWithoutDateField() {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, 2014, 1, 24);
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
                java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerFields = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    Log.i("test", datePickerField.getName());
                    if ("mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    if ("mMonthSpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    dpd.show();
}
```